# Orthogonal contrasts in R

Tags: anova, contrasts

I am having somewhat of a problem setting up contrasts from an anova in R. I have done this in the past, but at the moment I don't seem to be able to get R to use my contrast matrix instead of the treatment contrasts. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, I guess its possible I am making some basic mistake that I can not see.

(I am using R2.15.1)

My data consists of growth rate estimates for a 37 of bacterial clones. For these clones we measured growth rate multiple times (4-20) and we were wanting to simply know whether some of the the clones had a different growth rate (mu) from an ancestral clone (Anc).

So I set up an anova as:

```
m1<-aov(mu~clone)
```

which gave me a significant effect of clone:

```
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
clone        36  32.52  0.9033   2.986 3.98e-06 ***
Residuals   123  37.21  0.3025                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I then set up my contrast matrix

```
levels(clone)
 [1] "A21"  "A22"  "A23"  "A24"  "A25"  "A26"  "A27"  "A28"  "A29"  "A30" 
[11] "A31"  "A32"  "A33"  "A34"  "A35"  "A36"  "A37"  "A38"  "A39"  "A40" 
[21] "Anc"  "T126" "T127" "T128" "T129" "T130" "T131" "T132" "T133" "T134"
[31] "T135" "T35"  "T36"  "T37"  "T38"  "T39"  "T40"
```

As I wanted to compare all other clones to the Ancestral (Anc), I created a matrix with 36 columns in which I assigned 1 to Anc, -1 to the clone I wanted to compare and 0 to all others. Thus the matrix was as:

```
contrasts(clone)<-cbind(
c(-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0)
 ,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1))
```

Now, the problem is that when I rerun the anova and do summary.lm, I still get the treatment contrasts being used and obtain:

```
Call:
aov(formula = mu ~ clone)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.059077 -0.010799  0.000524  0.013324  0.057926 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.111175   0.011905   9.339 5.35e-16 ***
cloneA22    0.057165   0.016836   3.395 0.000923 ***
cloneA23    0.034798   0.016836   2.067 0.040843 *  
cloneA24    0.009232   0.016836   0.548 0.584436    
cloneA25    0.047776   0.016836   2.838 0.005316 ** 
cloneA26    0.013474   0.016836   0.800 0.425091    
cloneA27    0.012300   0.016836   0.731 0.466445    
cloneA28    0.047080   0.018185   2.589 0.010787 *  
cloneA29    0.036722   0.018185   2.019 0.045626 *  
cloneA30    0.035574   0.016836   2.113 0.036625 *  
cloneA31    0.060275   0.016836   3.580 0.000493 ***
cloneA32    0.045941   0.016836   2.729 0.007290 ** 
cloneA33    0.017751   0.016836   1.054 0.293792    
cloneA34    0.013581   0.016836   0.807 0.421418    
cloneA35    0.018089   0.016836   1.074 0.284750    
cloneA36    0.035200   0.016836   2.091 0.038607 *  
cloneA37    0.048030   0.016836   2.853 0.005086 ** 
cloneA38    0.046683   0.016836   2.773 0.006423 ** 
cloneA39    0.040877   0.016836   2.428 0.016632 *  
cloneA40    0.051376   0.016836   3.052 0.002790 ** 
cloneAnc    0.020183   0.013161   1.533 0.127727    
cloneT126   0.020191   0.016836   1.199 0.232738    
cloneT127   0.051375   0.016836   3.051 0.002790 ** 
cloneT128   0.043587   0.016836   2.589 0.010789 *  
cloneT129   0.038895   0.016836   2.310 0.022543 *  
cloneT130   0.017442   0.016836   1.036 0.302238    
cloneT131   0.020714   0.016836   1.230 0.220928    
cloneT132   0.038433   0.016836   2.283 0.024159 *  
cloneT133   0.028807   0.016836   1.711 0.089601 .  
cloneT134   0.037626   0.016836   2.235 0.027233 *  
cloneT135   0.017300   0.016836   1.028 0.306186    
cloneT35    0.050487   0.016836   2.999 0.003282 ** 
cloneT36    0.040415   0.016836   2.401 0.017871 *  
cloneT37    0.054457   0.016836   3.235 0.001565 ** 
cloneT38    0.041835   0.016836   2.485 0.014304 *  
cloneT39    0.038966   0.016836   2.314 0.022301 *  
cloneT40    0.025847   0.016836   1.535 0.127292
```

So here clone A21 is still being used for comparison.

Thanks in advance for any possible help,

Ricardo

Comment: You could try using the `contrast` package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/contrast/vignettes/contrast.pdf

Comment: You can change the reference level for your factor with `cloneRe <- relevel(clone, ref="A21")`. `aov(mu ~ cloneRe)` should then compare all groups against level `A21`.

Comment: Thanks very much to both answers. @caracal that solved my problem in a quite straightforward way and it will be extremely useful. Thank you

Comment: You can use the **lsmeans** package to get the results you need regardless of what contrasts are used in the model: 
`library("lsmeans");`
`m1.lsm <- lsmeans(m1, "clone");`
`contrast(m1.lsm, "trt.vs.ctrl", ref = 21)`